# Automatic email alerts from Zeppelin notebook

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I am new to Zeppelin, Before sending this post i have researched online but did not got a precise answer related to my requirement.

In one of our requirement in which we need to send automatic email alerts from Zeppelin notebook once our Spark SQL query result reaches upper control level or specific Threshold?

Our Process will run once in an hour.

How can we achieve this in  Zeppelin any suggestion or Help is Highly Appreciated

**Thank you in Advance for your Time and Help!!!..**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can send email using below SCALA Code using apache commons email library in Zeppelin

```
import org.apache.commons.mail._;
def Email(msg: String) =
{
 val email = new SimpleEmail();
      email.setHostName("webmail.abc.com"); //Emailbox URL
      email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("emailalert@abc.com", "XXXXXXX")); //Userid, Password
      email.setFrom("emailalert@abc.com"); //FROM
      email.setSubject("Email Send from Zeppelin"); //SUBJECT
      email.setMsg(msg); //Email Message 
      email.addTo("emailalert@abc.com"); //TO
      email.send()
}            

 Email("Count exceeded above threshold value 1500")
```

Even need to include following dependencies in order to work

Dependencies

artifact:

1) org.apache.commons:commons-email:1.4 
2) javax.mail:mail:1.4

exclude

1) com.sun.mail:javax.mail:1.5.2